# How would I use jquery to display a div containing text when clicking on a gallery thumbnail instead of the large image?

Tags: jquery

Here is the code as it stands, I have a larger image appear when clicking on a thumbnail. What I would like is to have a div containing descriptive text appear instead. This the jquery that does all of that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// Set these DIVs to show for browsers suporting JavaScipt
$('.gallery_data').css('display','block');
$('.gallery_thumbnails').css('width','500px');
$('.gallery_preview').css('display','block');
$('.gallery_caption').css('display','block');

// Capture the thumbnail links
$('.gallery_thumbnails a').click(function(e){

    // Disables standard link behavior
    e.preventDefault();

    /*
    // before the updateThumbnail function
    $('.gallery_thumbnails a').removeClass('selected');
    $('.gallery_thumbnails a').children().css('opacity', '1');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $(this).children().css('opacity', '.4');
    */


    // Sets up variables based on linked thumbnails
    var photo_caption = $(this).attr('title');
    var photo_fullsize = $(this).attr('href');
    var photo_preview = photo_fullsize.replace("_fullsize", "_preview");

    // Fade out preview, preload new image, fade preview back in
    $('.gallery_caption').slideUp(500);
    $('.gallery_preview').fadeOut(500, function(){

        //add the preload after the fadeOut has happened
        $('.gallery_preload_area').html('<img src="'+photo_preview+'">');
        $('.gallery_preload_area img').imgpreload(function(){

            //first without function
                $('.gallery_preview').html('<a class="overlayLink"         
title="'+photo_caption+'" href="'+photo_fullsize+'" style="background-
image:url('+photo_preview+');"></a>');
            $('.gallery_caption').html('<p><a class="overlayLink zoom"  
title="'+photo_caption+'" href="'+photo_fullsize+'">View larger</a>
</p><p>'+photo_caption+'</p>');

            $('.gallery_preview').fadeIn(500);
            $('.gallery_caption').slideDown(500);

            setFancyBoxLinks();
            updateThumbnails();
        });

    });

});

// Set the first preview image
var first_photo_caption = $('.gallery_thumbnails a').first().attr('title');
var first_photo_fullsize = $('.gallery_thumbnails a').first().attr('href');
var first_photo_preview = first_photo_fullsize.replace("_fullsize", "_preview");
$('.gallery_preview').html('<a class="overlayLink" title="'+first_photo_caption+'" 
href="'+first_photo_fullsize+'" style="background-image:url('+first_photo_preview+');">
</a>');
$('.gallery_caption').html('<p><a class="overlayLink zoom" 
title="'+first_photo_caption+'" href="'+first_photo_fullsize+'">View larger</a>
</p><p>'+first_photo_caption+'<a href="'+first_photo_fullsize+'" style="background-
image:url('+first_photo_preview+');"></a></p>');
updateThumbnails();
setFancyBoxLinks();

});

function setFancyBoxLinks(){
// Links for Facnybox
$("a.overlayLink").fancybox({
    'titlePosition' : 'over',
    'overlayColor' : '#000',
    'overlayOpacity' : 0.8,
    'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
    'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
    'autoScale' : true
});
}

function updateThumbnails(){
 $('.gallery_thumbnails a').each(function(index){

    if ( $('.gallery_preview a').attr('href') == $(this).attr('href') ){
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $(this).children().fadeTo(250, .4);
    }else {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
        $(this).children().css('opacity', '1');
    }
 });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
$('.gallery_preview').fadeIn(500);
$('.gallery_caption').slideDown(500);
```

to this

```
 $('.your_div_class_name').fadeIn(500);
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try that right now and let you know how it works

Comment: How would I be able to customize it so a different div (with an id or class) opens on the same area for each image. Lets say I create a div with content for each one and have them not display at first.

Comment: I am guessing I would need to build the different divs with content within what is currently .gallery_preview and change the content associated with it now. Not sure how to go about structuring it. Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: @OneSan you might need the `.each()` function which takes in all the collected elements you have in the selector. Look it up

Comment: Thank you for the help, my experience with jquery is kind of limited so I will try restructuring the code, that code is based on a gallery script so now I am trying to have it to do something different. I have to confess I am having a bit of a challenge on how I should structure my divs and then my jquery code.

Comment: @OneSan if you like describe clearly exactly what you would like to be done, and I will try to show you simply

Comment: Thank you so much In God I trust. So as it stands I have a gallery that now contains 17 images, I want to create a div with specific content for each one. The script right now displays a larger version of the thumbnail on click. I would like to have the div corresponding to each image to display instead. Not sure if it makes sense. Basically I will be trading the larger version of the thumbnail for a div containing some paragraphs of text. I hope it kind of makes sense.

Comment: @OneSan makes sense, will help soon

Comment: @OneSan lets start here, you understand whats going on? http://jsfiddle.net/GKUbG/

Comment: I think I understand what is going on yes, from what I can gather all my images would need to have the same class and the divs I want them to be associated with should have another but same class. This is the code I have to generate that gallery:

Comment: <div class="gallery_thumbnails">
                    <a href="images/gallery/picture1_fullsize.jpg" title="Andre Durie"><img src="images/gallery/picture1_thumbnail.jpg"/><span class="photo_caption">Andre Durie 
</span></a> 
</div>
And so on for each image.

Comment: I realize that code doesn't make much sense but I have all 17 <a> tags within the class gallery_thumbnails

Comment: @OneSan yeah, each time you enter a `click()` of an element, using `.this()` gets you that specifically clicked element, then search for the class you want inside `this` element using the `find` function, and do what you want with it!

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try to see if I am able to get it working. I really appreciate you taking the time to give me a hand.

Comment: @OneSan no problem, keep trying one line at a time, dont forget to use firebug on firefox to get the errors in a console.

Comment: @OneSan if you totally give up (which you shouldnt) maybe I'll hire out my services to you for a bit!

Comment: I will try my best, if i don't manage I will probably have to give it up for now. I am still working on learning jQuery, I can manage some simple stuff and figure out some scripts but I have a hard time creating some more complex things. I unfortunately don't have the means right now to hire sevices but I would if I could. I really thank you for taking the time to help me out. I will let you know if I manage to get the idea working.

Comment: @OneSan good for you. Take a look at http://www.lynda.com/jQuery-tutorials/essential-training/48370-2.html, its not amazing but it will definitely help you a lot